# Unknown terms of the proportion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

please help me solving this problem. The question is, find the unknown terms of the proportion $$\frac 23 = \frac x{12} = \frac y{15}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac 23 = \cfrac x{12}$$ $$\dfrac 23 =  \dfrac y{15}$$

Cross multiplying gives us the following equalities:

$$2\cdot 12 = 3x$$ $$2 \cdot 15 = 3y$$

Solve for $x$ and $y$.